# Noise reduction blur / postprocess in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blur

I use Photoshops Surface Blur to reduce the noise, but it operates only on 2D

Isn't there a way to blur in Blender, but also smarter then PS maybe using some extended info that Blender has?

I found http://mattebb.com/weblog/surface-blur/ , but the sample link is broken and quite old

**Any idea how to make "smart" blur directly in Blender?**

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: tutorial http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/02/18/blender-bilateral-blur-compositing-node/

Comment: isn't there a setup which doesn't need to be configured for each scene individually?

Comment: There is a nice setup in the demonstrated [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/02/25/noise-reduction-compositor/), which uses the bilateral blur node while taking the normals into account. It also allows you to control the blur on glossy/diffuse/transmitted etc. passes separately.

Comment: Is your example image a render or a photograph? If it's a render, take this as a compliment ;)

Comment: I bet for a render (all those toys must be expensive) :D

Answer (score 1):

Blender Compositor work only in 2D too..

"using some extended info that Blender has?" - You show a Photo.. What Info should Blender have that PS doesn't? ;-)

What you have in your Image here is actually not Noise, but Compression Artefacts.

I found this solution with Bilateral Blur works quite ok on your Sample:

[image: Blender Compression Artefacts Remove]

I doubt that any Noise Reduction on Images(not rendered) in Blender is much better than dedicated ones in Gimp or elsewhere. While Blenders Compositor allows some neat things, it does not give direct access to Pixels, which i think is needed for any decent Noise reduction. (Of course Node do access Pixels, but you have no way of access Pixels in you Node Setup)

Comment: hi, is there a .blend file for your node setup? thx

Comment: I would have to recreate it.. But it's only 3 different Nodes: Separate/Combine YUV in Converter (shift+a) and Bilateral Blur in Filter. I think you can easily do this?